# Database design: credit top-ups and transactions

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

We're in the business of lead generation. Customers receive leads from us. They view basic information about the lead and decide whether to accept the lead or reject. If they accept the lead, they are deducted 1 credit (for each lead) and they can view the detail info of the lead.

So each lead costs 1 credit (which is tied to some monetary value).

We have different type of customers: insurance agents, real estate agents, credit card companies, clubs, etc. They pay different price for 1 credit.

Customers can be prepaid or postpaid.

I have the following tables for all of the above:

```
Customers (id, name, address, is_postpaid, customer_type_id)
CustomerTypes (id, name, credit_price) // name: insurance agent, real estate agent, etc
TransactionTypes (id, name) // add to or deduct from credit balance
CustomerTransactions (id, customer_id, quantity, transaction_type_id, credit_balance, credit_unit_price, date_created)
```

Questions:

- What do you think about the overall approach?
- This design is OK for prepaid customers. But what about postpaid?

Any feedback and criticism is appreciated.

**Update:**: I've updated above tables to include the FK in Customers table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the grain of the transaction table is truly one transaction (no cumulative fields), than there is no difference between pre-paid and post-paid customers. You may enter payments as positive and debits as negative numbers in a same column, or (as some people prefer) use two columns for "positive and negative" customer transactions.

Customer balance can always be obtained by:

```
select
      CustomerName
    , sum(Credits) - sum(Debits) as AccountBalance
from Transactions as t
join Customer     as c  on c.CustomerId = t.CustomerId
group by CustomerName
order by CustomerName ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the database to the following:

Customers (id, name,customerType_id, address, is_postpaid)
CustomerTypes (id, name, credit_price)
CustomerTransactions (id, customer_id, quantity, transaction_type, credit_balance, credit_unit_price, date_created)

What I am not so sure is about the prepaid or postpaid concept. If you can please clarify it for me.

Comment: Prepaid means customer buys credit in advance (i.e. tops up her credit_balance with us). If she has zero balance, she won't be able to view leads. Postpaid means she doesn't have to maintain any credit_balance. At the month-end we'll charge her the usage (i.e. number of accepted leads). So, for example, we change $20 per accepted lead to insurance agents. If by month-end she accepted 100 leads, we'll charge her $2000.

Comment: You are proposing to add FK customer_type_id to table customers. Sorry, I forgot to add that. It's obvious. What do you suggest for postpaid customers? Make credit_balance go negative based on the number of usage?

Answer (score 0):

i would also suggest that there is no difference between pre and post pay - you just have transactions.

to accomodate the pre-post differences, you could introduce a new table that describes it:

```
    customer_type
    --------------
    id    
    pre_or_post
    begin_date
    end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing about credits is that from an accounting standpoint, they are a liability on the books if prepaid. They are sort of like gift cards, you can't recognize the revenue until the credits are used. With that in mind, you want to have credits expire after a certain length of time, like 1 year. Since credits expire, you then need to deduct credits in order, from oldest to newest.

You should have one table to record credit usage (i.e. CustomerCreditUsage), and another table for credit purchases (CustomerTransactions). Upon purchase, you check for negative credit balance and close out the record(s) from the credit usage table. If prepaid, when you record a credit usage transaction, you deduct from the credit balance of the oldest credit purchase.

Keep in mind that there is a loose relation between credit purchases and credit usage. You can have one without the other. Although you don't want to have a credit usage without a matching credit purchase for too long (post paid).